# UNIX date format in month day year format

Tags: unix

I want to display date in Month Day Year format in HP-UX and Korn shell - e.g. today's date should be displayed as `APR 6 2018`.

Comment: date +%b-%m-%Y ouptuts as Apr-04-2018,but i dont want - in between

Comment: date +'%b %m %Y'

Answer (score -1):

date +%b-%m-%Y | sed 's/-/ /g'

Comment: This answer would be slightly more useful (also more trustworthy) if you were to explain in English what it is doing.